# Avoid fragment recreation with hashmap

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity which handles 5 fragments. Every time the activity replaces each fragment onCreate and onCreateView are being called. In order to avoid this i created a HashMap where i store each fragment. Before the activity replaces a fragment it checks the hashmap if this fragment already exists. If it exists it replaces the old fragment with the instance from the map. In other case it instatiates the fragment and after that it replaces the old own.

Despite i avoid the instation of the fragment when i find it on hashmap, the onCreate and onCreateView are being called. How can i avoid this? Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no use for a HashMap to save the references of your Fragments. You can set a tag to a Fragment at the point you add/replace it. Have a look at the [FragmentTransaction.add(int, Fragment, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) and [FragmenTransaction.replace(int, Fragment, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) methods. If you provide a unique String for the tag you can retrieve the Fragment with the [FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) method. A container for Fragment references is redundant.

To the point:
If you use the replace/add method to show a Fragment the onCreate() and onCreateView() is called. To avoid the onCreate() call you can just attach and detach your Fragments. This way only onCreateView() will be invoked. But it's **not** possible to prevent the onCreateView() call.

Maybe update your question with some details what you want to achieve, because it sounds you are completely on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not very cleared.

When you deal with fragment, keep in mind that your control over their life cycle is limited, you only extend (system controlled) object. You can read on the life cycle of the fragment here: [Creating a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

Assuming your goal is to switch between 5 active fragments, I can think of two options:

option 1: design your fragment so they can be recreated quickly, maintain the data in some other place, and provide it to the fragment, which only do the work of display the data.

option 2: The android support library has two fragment adapters, [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), and [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).  The first is an adapter which keep the fragments in memory.

Answer (score -1):

> How can i avoid this? Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

If you really want to avoid your activity instance to be recreated again and again just use `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

**Example:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="SomeLabel"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

From developer docs,

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target
>   task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to
>   its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the
>   activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: An Activity will not be recreated on Fragment switches. Hence, this is no solution for OP's problem.